# Problea al traer la coleccion $workDays

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Como se evidencia en la BD, hay informacion y me debe traer la colección que se encuentra con la fecha en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de “ScheduleController.php --Api”, como se ve en la imagen este tiene la opción “true” y no trae la colección.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero no me trae la colección, me muestra el arreglo vacío “[]”, como se muestra nada:

Pero si coloco en el mismo código con “`false`” como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si me trae la colección, como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Vi en una pregunta anterior, al cual el compañero tiene el mismo problema, y en su respuesta dice:

> “Tienes una fila con active=1, por lo que debería devolverte una colección con un elemento. Si no lo hace es porque tal vez tus variables $day y $doctorId no coinciden con esa fila. Verifica sus valores antes de llegar a la consulta.”
> Pero no veo cual es el problema aun??

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


use App\WorkDay;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ScheduleController extends Controller
{
    public function hours(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'date' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',
            'doctor_id' => 'required|exists:users,id'
        ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules);
    //dd($request->all());
    $date = $request->input('date');
    $dateCarbon = new Carbon($date);
    
    //dayofWeek
    // Carbon: 0 (Domingo) - 6 (sábado)
    // WorkDay: 0 (Lunes) - 6 (Domingo)
    $i = $dateCarbon->dayOfWeek;
    $day = ($i == 0 ? 6 : $i-1);
    
    $doctorId = $request->input('doctor_id');


    $workDays = WorkDay::where('active', true)
        ->where('day', $day)
        ->where('user_id', $doctorId)
        ->get([
            'morning_start', 'morning_end',
            'afternoon_start', 'afternoon_end'
        ]);
    
     dd($day);
    //dd($workDays);

 }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No llevo mucho en Laravel, entonces no entiendo el porque, de lo que me han dicho es que estas variables $day y $doctorId no coinciden con la fila. pero ando medio perdido hay?
Gracias por su ayuda y paciencia.

Comment: dd($day); al colocar esta linea me da como resultado "1"

Comment: No deberías añadir imágenes. Con texto sería más sencillo ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Veamos unos detalles en la lógica que estás implementando:

- Tratas de obtener el registro que esta activo en tu tabla, el cual corresponde al índice 3 (que sería el día: miércoles)
- Posterior cuando tratas de almacenar en una variable el índice del día actual estarías guardando como valor: **N** (*que será dinámico y se tomará en función del día y la zona horaria configurada*)
- No entiendo para que manipular de esa forma la fecha y el índice del día, con *Carbon* podemos obtener la fecha actual de acuerdo con la zona horaria que hayas configurado en el proyecto, entonces para este punto yo lo dejaría así:

  ```
  $day = now()->dayOfWeek();
  ```
- Sin embargo luego haces una evaluación en un *if* ternario indicando esto:

> Si el índice encontrado es igual a 0, es decir día domingo entonces el valor que tomará la variable será el índice 6 que corresponde al día sábado, sino será el índice del día actual - 1 que (*nuevamente si lo ejecutamos el día lunes por ejemplo*) nos llevará al índice del día anterior que sería el domingo.

Es decir al final tu condición de filtrado en el primer `where` no se va a cumplir por que los índices de los días no empatan y como estás encadenando 2 de estos métodos `where`, es como si dijeras *necesito que el índice del día sea igual a X **y** que el id del user sea igual a Y*, algo así:

```
  WHERE algo = otro AND fulano = mengano
```

Llegados al punto anterior, **me parece que lo que se debe replantear es como armas la consulta, por que no existe garantía de que las 3 condiciones se cumplan** y al momento eso es lo que estás solicitando, puede que sea mejor hacer opcional una o varias de ellas.

Consulta:

```
$workDays = WorkDay::whereUserId($doctorId)
                   ->whereActive(true)
                   ->orWhere('day', $day)
                   ->get();
```

En la consulta anterior, por ejemplo le indico que ontenga todos los modelos de `WorkDay` donde el id del usuario sea igual a algo y que el estado sea activo o donde el índice el día sea igual a algo.

> Por cierto colocando false si te devuelve resultados por que ejecutando este código si existen índices de días almacenados que empaten con el índice que obtienes en tu código PHP; es decir existen renglones que SI están cumpliendo las 3 condiciones exigidas.

Checa además https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Por cierto colocando `false` si te devuelve resultados por que ejecutando este código si existen índices de días almacenados que empaten con el índice que obtienes en tu código PHP; *es decir existen renglones que **SI** están cumpliendo las 3 condiciones exigidas*